# SWT StyledText and Paragraph Spacing

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

StyledText.setLineSpacing() allows line spacing, where each line (whether wrapped or following a carriage return) is separated from its predecessor.

Is there a way to set *paragraph* spacing, where wrapped lines sit together normally, but a carriage return inserts extra space?

(I want the final result to look much like this question, but without pressing enter twice between paragraphs.)

I am using both a StyledTextContent and a LineStyleListener.  Ideally, I'd like to set paragraph spacing on each paragraph via the LineStyleListener, but I would settle for a document-wide solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to modify the text itself as you write it to and read it from the `StyledText`.

Basically, you want to replace a single line feed with a double line feed when you `setText`, and replace a double line feed with a single line feed when you `getText`.

You'll also have to write a `VerifyKeyListener`, that replaces a single line feed with a double line feed.

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` will be helpful, although your file line feed might not match your system line separator.